# Tap-to-wake anywhere without activating anything when the screen starts dimming

Tags: settings, lock-screens

I'm an iPhone user. Sorry for that.
But in my defense, I was given a recent Android phone and like it!

However, I noticed a difference in the Auto-Lock behavior that is, to me, utterly annoying.
Maybe people here used to the thing might enlighten the poor iPhone user that I am.

- On an iPhone, about 10 seconds before entering auto-lock, the screen dims. Same on Android.
- Then, tapping anywhere on the iPhone screen before the lock occurs, the dimming stops, the iPhone is ready to be used again *and* that's it. The location where the "tapping" took place is *not* activated. It's simply ignored.
- *However*, on Android, while the screen is dimmed and one can barely see where the tapping takes place, the "tapped" location *is* activated! So whatever was tapped is run!

Most of the time, tapping the dimmed phone is just to wake it up. So, I tried to educate myself, and find an icon-less area to tap whenever I want to wake up the device. But sometimes it's within an app...
Compared to the no-brainer action on an iPhone, that's really annoying.

Searched the settings, the iPhone behavior does not seem to be possible on an Android phone.

This is **the** reason I wouldn't switch to Android.
Most probably, Android users are used to that behavior and do not care (/ don't know that the behavior could be different).

Is there a way to set that iPhone behavior on Android?

Comment: It's the default behavior and I don't know if it can be changed. You can try [an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.k2.no.screen.off) to prevent screen from turning off when you need or switch to default behavior. There are plenty of other apps which offer an alternative (search for "tap to wake up screen") but they don't actually do what you want or apps like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doublep.wakey)

Comment: that is exactly why I don't tap the screen and scroll to wake the screen up

Comment: As Pouya Danesh suggested, instead of taping try swiping up/ down, it will wake up without registering any tap.

Comment: @PouyaDanesh A  simple no-brainer less error prone simple tap solution would be better, but thanks for the workaround, not ideal, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the *sleep* option. You can do this by going to **settings>display>sleep** and then choose an option according to your preference. Some phones(like Redmi or Mi phones) come with a *never sleep* option whereas others can stay awake for a maximum of 30 minutes.

Comment: Thx. The problem is not the time-to-sleep, it's the "dim-wakeup".